# Not possible to initialize C++ vector from pointer

Tags: cython

I'd like to initialize a C++ STL vector by using the

```cpp
template<class InputIt>
std::vector(InputIt first, InputIt last);
```

constructor in Cython. Here's a simple example:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
cnp.import_array()

def foo(double[::1] a):
    cdef vector[double] vec = vector[double](&a[0], &a[0] + a.size)
    # do something with vec..
```

However, this yields the error message

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def foo(double[::1] a):
    cdef vector[double] vec = vector[double](&a[0], &a[0] + a.size)
                                                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_c522d88d9553084771dd501620335f85a93b04ae.pyx:5:52: Cannot convert 'double *' to Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def foo(double[::1] a):
    cdef vector[double] vec = vector[double](&a[0], &a[0] + a.size)
                                            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_c522d88d9553084771dd501620335f85a93b04ae.pyx:5:45: Cannot assign type 'double *' to 'size_type
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: At a guess you aren't compiling it in C++ mode

Comment: It seems like the desired constructor is not available, see [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/42a4af2ffdf96949a33684c1a692803bbb519362/Cython/Includes/libcpp/vector.pxd#L46).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, your desired constructor is not available inside Cython. AFAIK, Cython doesn't support templated constructors yet. As a workaround, you could use [`.assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign), i.e.:

```py
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def foo(double[::1] a):
    cdef vector[double] vec
    vec.assign(&a[0], &a[0] + <size_t>a.size)
    # do something with vec..
```